# JQuery способ применения функции?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
$('#loader').show();
        get("req.php", {
            plugin:pay_type.value,
            type:'verify',
            account:account.value,
            language:language.value,
            jek:jek.value,
            period:period.value
        }, parse_answer);
        return true;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как поправить?

**Обновление**

Так с этим вроде бы разобрался, но теперь, смотрите, другая ошибка:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pay_type is not defined

Код строки:

```
 get("req.php", {
            plugin:pay_type.value,
            type:'verify',
            account:account.value,
            language:language.value,
            jek:jek.value,
            period:period.value
        }, parse_answer);
        return true;
    }
```

`plugin:pay_type.value` - здесь ошибку выдает.

Comment: @AndyLarkin, jQuery подключен? Выложите код на jsfiddle.net.

Comment: так с этим вроде б разобрался, но теперь смотрите другая ошибка:
Uncaught ReferenceError: pay_type is not defined 
Код строки:
 get("req.php", {
            plugin:pay_type.value,
            type:'verify',
            account:account.value,
            language:language.value,
            jek:jek.value,
            period:period.value
        }, parse_answer);
        return true;
    }

plugin:pay_type.value ---- здесь ошибку выдает

Comment: `pay_type is not defined` - объект pay_type не определен. Этот объект где-то уже определен конструкциями `var`, `let` и т.п.?